# Draw 4 straight lines to create 10 equal squares in this image

Tags: geometry, strategy

You can draw up to 4 straight lines in order to create 10 equal squares in the following figure:

[image: puzzle of two squares]

Answer (score 45, accepted):

Please ignore my painting skill. i am not good at it

> [image]

Comment: Beat me to it..!

Comment: Man, I turned on gridlines in Paint and everything!

Comment: Same here: got the 1 new answer just as I finished drawing it. :(

Comment: ohhh !! finally i beat someone . This time i didn't care about the look and cleanness

Comment: MarkN , Bailey and Spencerkatty first time i beat someone

Comment: Correct answer. This question was asked in a interview

Comment: dont forget to mark it as a correct answer.

Comment: I'm sorry but this cannot be correct. You need to draw these lines exactly in the middle of the squares, and you would need additional lines to find the middle. This may be the "intended" answer, but you cannot claim that you have drawn squares of the same size unless you have a way to put the four needed lines in the right place. I think that's a fault of the question, not the answer.

Comment: @Floris Seriously??? Though if you are going to be *that* picky, why would you have to draw extra lines to find the middle? Why couldn't you rig up a contraption to help find the exact middle without drawing any extra lines? And even then wouldn't you always run the risk of being at the very least several femtometers off?

Comment: @Warlord099 - normally when you do a geometric construction there is the assumption that when you draw a straight line from point A to point B, it is a straight line from point A to point B. And the question states "draw straight lines", not "use contraption XYZ". So I consider that you have to solve the problem (of finding the middle of the squares, and drawing properly horizontal and vertical lines through those middles) using just straight lines. But then you need more than four. And indeed the assumption that the drawing has squares is implicit as well.

Comment: First of all, the "question" most definitely is not a question. The title is a command and the body is a statement, so yes it is a poorly worded question. Secondly, I do not see "geometric construction" so that appears to be an assumption on your part. Thirdly, I assumed the question was about where to place the lines and not how to place the lines (seeing as the OP accepted this answer I am assuming I am correct). Fourthly, this answer most definitely should have a paragraph describing the placement of the lines to make up for its crude drawing.

Comment: The question is tagged with "geometry". Maybe I am just a stickler and this is the wrong place for me.

Comment: This was a interview question as mentioned earlier, so the interview just want to test your logical thinking. It is just a solution to the problem. Somebody can edit the question and answer for better clarity.

Answer (score 21):

Kavi Temre got this first, but here's my unnecessarily clear image:

> [image]

Comment: Good one. We have same logical thinking

Comment: Wait don't lines extend infinitely though? /s

Comment: Yeah, these are just segments.

Comment: Well, if we're talking like that then that can't be the definition of a line in this context. The question said "you **can** draw up to 4 straight lines". If, however, a line was infinite, I wouldn't be able to draw it. ;D

Comment: @Samthere: Sure you can, the question says so :-)

Answer (score 6):

I need 12 lines - 8 to find the centers of the large squares (thanks Aragaer for noticing that we get the center "for free"), then 4 to create the 10 equal squares. You could argue that the 10 dashed lines are not drawn as part of the "creating squares". In fact, you could use a ruler to draw just the little orange "helper marks" in order to do the construction.

It does assume that the two initial shapes are squares.

> [image]

Comment: You could use just 8 dashed lines. Either 4 and 5 or 6 and 7 could be dropped, the other two will work. You do have the center of the image.

Comment: @aragaer Good call - I missed the center point. I will update.

Comment: Well done Floris +1 for dotted lines